# Error in readRDS(f) : embedded nul in string: 'at_type_sum\0\004\0\tsl\002ma'

Tags: r

I have an issue with the help() function in R and hope that someone here will be able to provide an answer.

Whenever I load a pacakage (doesn't matter which one), and try to use the help function, I get confronted with the following error message:

```
Error in readRDS(f) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'at_type_sum\0\004\0\tsl\002ma'
```

I have shown this problem to multiple people, and apparently it seems to be a rare issue. The weird thing is that the help function works fine just after opening Rstudio. However, once I load a package, it stops working and gives me the error message. It also doesn't matter which function I type within the help function, it will always return the same error message...

The output of sessionInfo() is the following:

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Switzerland.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Switzerland.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Switzerland.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=English_Switzerland.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.2 tools_4.2.2
```

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing R and Rstudio, but the problem still persists. I also tried updating all my packages and that didn't change things. As using the help function is pretty fundamental in learning R, I would love some help on this issue.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Could be an error/corruption in the path of of the help files. Or in the `utils` package itself. Which version of R are you using and which OS? Does the documentation work. (using  F2 , or ??functionname )

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75781767/edit) your question with output of `sessionInfo()` as well as RStudio version. Does the issue persist when R using in the command line?

Comment: It might be that "one" (or more) package in your personal library is corrupted? Try moving your personal library path out of the way (the non-system path found in `.libPaths()`, the default location differs by OS); then restart R and try again. If this fixes it, then you can either attempt to find which package in that subdir is corrupted (the most-recently updated might be a safe start) or just reinstall all of them.

Comment: The use of `readRDS(f)` is found in two locations in the `utils` package: within [`packageDescription`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/38ce93ec22b4623de7161aaae8aece37182f06cf/src/library/utils/R/indices.R#L63) and again in [`matchAvailableTopics`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/38ce93ec22b4623de7161aaae8aece37182f06cf/src/library/utils/R/completion.R#L452), and it could be either. This further suggests that one of the packages' files (within `./help/` or `./Meta/` subdirs) is corrupted.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user12256545 I am using the R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt) and I am using R on Windows 11

Comment: @r2evans Okay, how would I know which file is corrupted and what to do in order to fix the issue? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: You can try to read "all" aliases files with something like `for (fn in list.files(.libPaths()[1], pattern="aliases\\.rds", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)) { message(fn); ign <- readRDS(fn); }`, where an error (if present) will come immediately after the file being attempted. If that produces no errors, you can vary that with: (1) other components of `.libPaths()`, not just `[1]`; (2) `"package.rds"` or `"Rd.rds"` instead of `"aliases.rds"`.